# Energy Market Simulation using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, simulation

I have a long code (430 lines) which is used to simulate an energy market following specific guidelines.

Four different processes: Home, Market, Weather, External.

Each process has a specific task listed below:

Home has an production and consumption float value, a trade policy as an integer and calculates energy exchanges between each home (multiple home processes are created for the simulation).

Market calculates the current energy price based on the production and consumption and external factors.

Weather determines random variables of temperature and season to be used in Market.

External is a child process of Market and provides random external factors I have created.

I have an issue in my code where I create a new thread to display the results of each day of the simulation (days pass every 2 seconds) but I feel my code doesn't launch the thread properly and I'm quite lost as to where the issue is occuring exactly and why. I have used various print(".") to show where the program goes and identify where it doesn't and I can't see why the thread doesn't launch properly.

I am on Windows and not Linux. If this could be the issues, please tell me. I will show a code snippet below of where the issue seems to be and the full code as well as a pdf explaining in more detail how the project should run in a github link (430 lines of code doesn't seem reasonable to post here).

```
def terminal(number_of_homes, market_queue, home_counter, clock_ready, energy_exchange_queue, console_connection, console_connection_2):
day = 1

while clock_ready.wait(1.5 * delay):
    req1, req2, req3, req4 = ([] for i in range(4))

    for i in range(number_of_homes):
        a = market_queue.get()
        req1.append(a)
    req1 = sort(req1)

    for i in range(number_of_homes):
        a = market_queue.get()
        req1.append(a)
    req2 = sort(req2)

    for i in range(number_of_homes):
        a = market_queue.get()
        req1.append(a)
    req3 = sort(req3)

    req1 = req1 + req2 + req3

    for i in range(energy_exchange_queue.qsize()):
        b = energy_exchange_queue.get()
        req4.append(b)
    req4 = sort(req4)

    thread = threading.Thread(target = console_display, args = (number_of_homes, req1, day, req4, console_connection.recv(), console_connection_2.recv()))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

    day += 1
```

Github link: https://github.com/MaxMichel2/Energy-Market-Project